# Update database table through jsp to jsp

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp

**View.jsp**

this jsp to fetching the data from the database.

```
<form method="post" action="updatedemo.jsp"> 
 <table width="50%" border="1" align="center">                
   <tr>
     <td width="41%" height="32"><em><strong>name</strong></em></td>
     <td width="59%">                     
        <input type="text" name="name" value="<%= resultset.getString(1) %>">                
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td height="34"><em><strong>lastname</strong></em></td>
     <td>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" value="<%= resultset.getString(2) %>">
     </td>                      
     <input type="submit" name="submit">                    
    </form>                      
    <% 
     } 
     %>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

**Update.jsp**

This is the update Query But This is not working and redirecting to the update.jsp but nothing displayed

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>

<%

String name=request.getParameter("name");
//int no=Integer.parseInt(code);
String lastname=request.getParameter("lastname");
try{
Connection conn = null;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo","root", "jack");
Statement st=null;
st=conn.createStatement();




String sqlEDIT="UPDATE INTO demoproject(name,lastname) VALUES(?,?)";
java.sql.PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(sqlEDIT);
ps.setString(1,name);
ps.setString(2,lastname);

ps.executeUpdate();
   int i=ps.executeUpdate();
if(i>0)
        {
            out.print("project added into database");
            response.sendRedirect("demo1.jsp");
        }
}
catch(Exception e){
System.out.println(e);
    }
%>
```

> When I pressed the Submit button, it redirected me to Update.jsp and
>   nothing was changed in database .

Comment: Its not `UPDATE INTO demoproject` , `insert INTO demoproject` perhaps ?

Comment: Query is wrong its INSERT INTO instead of UPDATE INTO..

Comment: General rule when writing JSPs get your java code in a bean and reference the bean in the JSP.  It will aĺlow a great deal of simplification.

Comment: The answer is here: `catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e); }`. Just replace `System.out.println(e);` by `throw new ServletException(e);`. You'll then get a normal error page with a googleable exception. Which can indicate a self-explaining SQL syntax error or even just a CNFE on the JDBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

- You are using Update query instead of Insert query.
- Writing Java code inside JSP not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Your update syntax is wrong.
It should look like:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```